# pocketsphinx seg fault with ps_start_utt

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, pocketsphinx

I am trying to use pocketsphinx as part of a c++ program and have a problem when running my code. I had two issues: The first being that my microphone wasn't being recognized by pocketsphinx and the second being a seg fault when ps_start_utt was called. I'm running this on ubuntu 14.04. Here is the original code:

```
ps_decoder_t *ps;
cmd_ln_t *config;       
ad_rec_t *ad;

config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
        "-hmm", "/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us",
        "-lm", "../audio/1638.lm",
        "-dict", "../audio/1638.dic",
        "-logfn", "/dev/null",
        NULL);
ps = ps_init(config);             
ad = ad_open_dev("sysdefault", (int) cmd_ln_float32_r(config, "-samprate"));
// below is the other thing I tried to use to open the audio device.
// ad = ad_open();
cout << "AAAA" << endl;
ad_start_rec(ad);
cout << "BBBB" << endl;
ps_start_utt(ps);
cout << "CCCC" << endl;
utt_started = FALSE;
```

When executed, this produced two errors at the command line. The first was an error about being unable to find the `sysdefault` audio device and the second was a seg fault that occurred after `AAAA` and `BBBB` were outputted (`CCCC` was never printed).
This means that something in `ps_start_utt` is causing a seg fault but I have no idea what. I originally thought the two errors were related so I tried to fix the first one. By replacing the string `sysdefault` with `NULL` in `ad_open_dev` the first error no longer appears but the seg fault still happens.
Using `ad_open()` instead of `ad_open_dev` is the same as substituting `NULL`; the first error is no longer present but the seg fault still occurs in the same place. However, the strangest thing to me about this issues is that the `pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes` command works perfectly on the same machine with the same mic. I have looked at the `continuous.c` code on the `cmusphinx` repository but haven't been able to figure out what the difference is or how I might correct it.  I can post more of the code if necessary. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: After doing some checks I found that the error that causes the seg fault is that ps == NULL. I'm still not sure why this would be happening however.

Comment: Remove this line  `"-logfn", "/dev/null"`, and you'll get more detailed error messages